# Dynamic pivoting SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-pivot

I am making attempts to run my first dynamic pivot in SQL Server 2012.

My `#temp` table that I am using for the dynamic pivoting looks like this.

```
YearMonth   Agreement nr    Discount
------------------------------------
201303         123            1
201303          12            0
201304           1            0
```

I am running this code and it does not work:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(YearMonth )
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YearMonth FROM #FINAL) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT [Agreement nr],YearMonth , ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #FINAL
    PIVOT(
            COUNT(agreement nr) 
          FOR YearMonth IN (' + @ColumnName + ') AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query

EXECUTE  @DynamicPivotQuery;
```

The error message I am getting is

> FOR YearMonth IN ([201403]) AS PVTTable' is not a valid identifier.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that you're missing a parenthesis before you alias the Pivot. More than this however your pivot was rather inefficient.

You should select what you need for the source table in your pivot otherwise it could run for a long time and produce a lot of rows with null returns.

The below is fixed and hopefully more efficient:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(YearMonth )
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YearMonth FROM #FINAL) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM (Select [Agreement nr], YearMonth from #FINAL) src
    PIVOT(
            COUNT([Agreement nr]) 
          FOR YearMonth IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;
```

Comment: I tried the solution and it throws an error: COUNT(Agreement nr) 
          FOR YearMonth IN ([201503],[201506],[201504],[201505])) AS PVTTable' is not a valid identifier. Could it have to do that a GROUP BY is needed since we are doing COUNT and not doing a GROUP BY containing the YearMonth?

Comment: Try put "Agreement nr" in square brackets too: [Agreement nr]

Comment: Interesting. I put the brackets around it and it still throws the same error:Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
The name 'SELECT [Agreement nr],YearMonth, [201503],[201506],[201504],[201505]
    FROM (Select [Agreement nr], YearMonth from #tester) src
    PIVOT(
            COUNT([Agreement nr]) 
          FOR YearMonthIN ([201503],[201506],[201504],[201505])) AS PVTTable' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Have you tried running the statement normally and hard coding in the @ColumnName values?

Comment: Ok I figured out what was happening here. You need to sp_executesql to execute the statement. You also can't have Agreement nr or YearMonth in the select as you are making YearMonth into columns so you can't make it rows too and you're also populating the columns with the count of Agreement nr so that can't be rows either. Make sense?

I've updated the code above to reflect this

Comment: Thank you Christian. I am understand it better now.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT [Agreement nr],YearMonth , ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #FINAL
    PIVOT(
            COUNT([agreement nr]) 
          FOR YearMonth IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close pivot.

```
PIVOT(
        COUNT(Kundavtalid) 
        FOR YearMonth IN (' + @ColumnName + ') 
     ) AS PVTTable' -- here you miss pathernesis
```